# php key() function not working inside object

Tags: php, sockets, key

i have this function to get the index key of an element in $clientsObjects array.
each element in the array keeps an object of the Client class which have a getSocket() method which returns a socket resource.

i'm 100% sure the the $socket function parameter is equal to one of the Client->getSocket() which are in the array.
from some reason the code never enters the if statement...
any suggestions ?

```
function getClientObjectKey($socket)
{       
    global $clientsObjects;             
    while ($sock = current($clientsObjects))
    {                       
        if ($sock->getSocket() == $socket)          
            return key($clientsObjects);    
        $sock = next($clientsObjects);
    }           
}
```

Comment: Can you add a print statement inside of your loop, to ensure that it's even getting inside of the loop?

Comment: `var_dump($sock->getSocket());` and `var_dump($sock->getSocket());` You'll see full information about them.

Comment: Does it work if you call `reset($clientsObjects)` first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do the same using [`foreach`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) wich would give you direct access to the key and do the iteration for you, sop you don't have to mess around with `current`, `next` and `key`:

```
foreach ($clientsObjects as $key => $sock){                       
  if ($sock->getSocket() == $socket)          
    return $key;    
}
```

anyway, using `key()` shouldn't be a problem in your case, so i assume there's a difference between the objects you try to compare.

Comment: His problem could be that he never resets the internal pointer in `$clientsObjects`. i.e., His code might only work the first call. But I would agree with your recommendation to use `foreach` regardless of that.